# Rank a vector based on order in R

Tags: r, rank

I want to rank a column of a data frame but I want it to be ranked based on its order not ascending or descending order. Something like below:

```
> test <- c(0,0,0,2,1,5,3)
```

and then rank like this:

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

What is the easiest way of doing it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: how would handle repeats non-consecutively? ex: `test <- c(0,2,1,0,3,5,3)`?

Comment: @Arun Actually the important factor is only "order" of elements and so in your example the second zero should get rank=4. so the total rank should be:([1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ) for your example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `rle`:

```
test = c(0,0,0,2,1,5,3)
rle_test = rle(test)
ordered = rep(1:length(rle_test$lengths), rle_test$lengths)
```

Output:

```
> ordered
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would use the ties="dense" option of frankv() in data.table package:

> x
>
> [1] 12  9  5  7 15  7  7  8  7 13  6 12  7 12  5  2  8 28 20  9 10  3 12  6  1
>
> frankv(x,ties="dense")
>
> [1] 10  8  4  6 12  6  6  7  6 11  5 10  6 10  4  2  7 14 13  8  9  3 10  5  1